# Find and return a class based on a string

Tags: c#, .net

I have multiple classes of the parent class "command_functions"

example

```
class Empty_Command : command_functions
```

each of the command classes override a value

```
public override string command_display_name { get { return "Empty"; } }
```

is there anyway to search types of command_functions looking for where command_display_name is set to a matching string and return that.

so I could use it like so

```
command_functions find = FindCommand("Empty");
if(find != null)
{
    new find();
}
```

Comment: Why you want to realize such behavior?

Comment: the system needs to be able to select commands by name in a way thats easy to add new commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Generics this can be done. From what I can tell is you have a set of classes that inherit from a class Empty_Command (I am assuming abstract) and you would like to find which specific class to execute based on command name.

I have created the following example which assumes that all the inherited types are in the same assembly. Its no problem if they are across multiple assemblies just your load is different.

```
public abstract class Empty_Command
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Find command
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="commandName">the command name</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Empty_Command FindCommand(string commandName)
    {
        //get all the types that are inherited from the Empty_Command class and are not abstract (skips empty commad)
        var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(x => typeof(Empty_Command).IsAssignableFrom(x) && !x.IsAbstract);
        //enuerate all types
        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            //create an instance of empty command from the type
            var item = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as Empty_Command;
            if (item == null)
                continue;
            //test the display name
            if(item.command_display_name.Equals(commandName))
                return item;
        }
        return null;
    }
    public abstract string command_display_name { get; }
}
```

I commented a bit of the code to help out. But here is my full test stub.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cmd = Empty_Command.FindCommand("command_2");
            if (cmd != null)
                Console.WriteLine(cmd.command_display_name);
            Console.ReadKey();


        }
    }

    public abstract class Empty_Command
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Find command
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="commandName">the command name</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Empty_Command FindCommand(string commandName)
        {
            //get all the types that are inherited from the Empty_Command class and are not abstract (skips empty commad)
            var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(x => typeof(Empty_Command).IsAssignableFrom(x) && !x.IsAbstract);
            //enuerate all types
            foreach (var type in types)
            {
                //create an instance of empty command from the type
                var item = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as Empty_Command;
                if (item == null)
                    continue;
                //test the display name
                if(item.command_display_name.Equals(commandName))
                    return item;
            }
            return null;
        }
        public abstract string command_display_name { get; }
    }

    public class Command1 : Empty_Command
    {
        public override string command_display_name
        {
            get { return "command_1"; }
        }
    }

    public class Command2 : Empty_Command
    {
        public override string command_display_name
        {
            get { return "command_2"; }
        }
    }

    public class Command3 : Empty_Command
    {
        public override string command_display_name
        {
            get { return "command_3"; }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Small note:
one of my classes had a start arg and Activator.CreateInstance(type) hanged on it without warning.

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of a non-static property you need to instantiate the type, therefore the first condition is that you can instantiate each type you wish to examine.

Otherwise it is a matter of using reflection to get a list of types, filtering by base type, instantiating and calling the property get method.

Comment: If her really wants reflection, he could also introduce a `CommandDisplayNameAttribute` class and apply that attribute to all the classes in question.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen There are multiple ways this could be made easier (eg. a common interface, make the display name static), but at the core the process of find remains the same: get all types and then filter.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a Factory design pattern. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

In this Factory you can create a function like

```
command_functions findCommand(string commandText)
{
  if (commandText == "empty") return new Empty_Command();
  if (...) etc
}
```

Comment: I already had a massive switch case, that acted as like this [should have said so in the Q] but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following pattern to do that

```
interface IGroup2
        {
            string SearchOption { get; set; }
            List<Projects> GetProjects();
        }

        public class GroupHead : IGroup2
        {
            public string SearchOption { get; set; }

            public GroupHead()
            {
                SearchOption = "GroupHead";
            }

            public List<Projects> GetProjects()
            {   
                //Code here
                return null;
            }
        }

        public class ProjectIncharge : IGroup2
        {
            public string SearchOption { get; set; }

            public ProjectIncharge()
            {
                SearchOption = "ProjectIncharge";
            }

            public List<Projects> GetProjects()
            {
                //Code here
                return null;
            }
        }

        public class ProjectManager : IGroup2
        {
            public string SearchOption { get; set; }

            public ProjectManager()
            {
                SearchOption = "ProjectManager";
            }

            public List<Projects> GetProjects()
            {
                //Code here
                return null;
            }
        }

public class Test
{
        private static List<IGroup2> searchRuleList = new List<IGroup2>()
        {
          new GroupHead(),
          new ProjectIncharge(),
          new ProjectManager(),
        };

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
         IGroup2 searchOptionRule = searchRuleList.Find(delegate(IGroup2 searchRule) { return searchRule.SearchOption.Equals(args[0]); });

        } 
}
```